# Setting colors for gant-chart based on percentage values (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, gantt-chart, gant

I created a gantt-chart in excel which contains different projects and their planned start and end dates.

I want to modify this chart in the following way:
there is a changing percentage value, which shows the progress of the project.
Depending on the value, I would like the Bar to reflect this percentage, i.e. if "Validierungsplan" is 25%, i would like the first 25% of the bar to be green, the last 75% of the bar to be red.

I tried different methods, of which none worked. I believe VBA is needed, and sadly I do not have experience with this.

You will find a screenshot showing the situation, including an example for "Validierungsplan" how I would like the bars to look.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you look at Jon Peltier's [page on bar charts](https://peltiertech.com/floating-bars-excel-charts/) to see which approach fits your data best. You'll likely have to modify some part of your solution - the data on the worksheet and/or the vba to create the chart to match your needs.

Comment: You probably need to workaround this and split the date 2020-01-01 to 2020-03-03 into 2 (virtually) parts (first part 25% which you can color green and second part 75% which you color red). So first part would be from  2020-01-01 to 2020-01-16 (15 days = 25%) and second part 2020-01-16 to 2020-03-03 (47 days = 75%). • Not sure if that would be able to appear in the same line then, but give it a try.

Comment: Fabian, how did you create the Gantt chart in the first place? Are you using a plugin?